# How can I prevent someone using a promo code twice?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a database that looks like this:

[image: database]

When user wants to use a promo code, it first checks if **used_promo** is null, that means the user has not used any promo code before. (User can only use 1 promo code)

I can do something like this

```
SELECT used_promo FROM users WHERE id=5
```

then I can check with PHP if used_promo is null and if it is, I can do

```
UPDATE users SET used_promo=2, balance=balance+100 WHERE id=5
```

Is it possible that the user can try to use the promo code multiple times at the same time, the SELECT will return that **used_promo** is null before it is set to 2 and the balance will be added multiple times?

Comment: Options: use transactions, or simply addd the condition to the update.

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for the answer, I have thought of both these options, I think a condition in the UPDATE would be a good solution, I'm not really good with SQL, could you please write how the code would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you've described it's theoretically possible to use the promo code multiple times. Use a single query, which will return an id if the update is successful or no rows otherwise.

```
UPDATE users 
SET used_promo=2, balance=balance+100 
WHERE id=5 AND used_promo is null
RETURNING id;
```

Comment: Haven't thought of this, I'll definietly use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create one more relational table "promo_used", where columns would be:

1. id
2. user_id
3. promo_code_id
4. timestamp

Once user apply promo code, this table will have new entry. This way, if user tries to apply same promo code again, we can check by searching through this table.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As understood you are worried that a user may use promo code multiple times before you update used_promo column. I don't know what your business model is. However, it is possible in a scenario like this:

> User enters the promo code. You reduce the price of item accordingly, but you can't update the used_promo field since purchase is not complete. Without completing the purchase user enters the promo code for another product and gets a reduction again. And after doing this multiple time times user goes completing purchases. Since you don't check the validity of the code at the final step user can get all the price reductions.

So

- Maintain the validity status of promo code
- Always check the validity
- Use atomic way to update validity status, used_promo and finalize the purchase. (Transactions)

  of promo code and used_promo before finalizing purchase

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't think you understand how the promo code works. When user uses a promo code, it gives him free balance on the site to spend, the user doesn't use a promo code to get a discount when purchasing stuff.